# working with dictionary or lists python

Tags: python

I have a the following statement

```
onehot  = collection.defaultdict(list)
```

that I fill with  two dimentional vector.
when I print `onehot` here is what I get:

```
print(onehot)
--->defaultdict<class'list'>,{0:['1200',1],1:['1203',2],2:['1400',4]}
```

which is perfect . Now my question is is there a way to get the 'paired' value from onehot . for example:

```
onehot 1200 ---> 1 
onehot 1800 ---> 32
```

I'm newbie to python so I'm not sure about it.

**Update**
the problem is that I don't really know where 1200 is in the list, so I want and  I'm interested  in the number in  the 2nd dimension.
So  I need to the the list look for 1200 and return the values of the 2nd dimension which in this case is 1

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. `onehot[0]` gets you the list `['1200', 1]`, is that not what you want?

Comment: Where does `1800 -->  32` come from? I don't see it in the input.

Comment: @PaulRooney I suppose this is just an example

Comment: @PaulRooney  yes it's just an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a function that returns the second element in the list and uses the first element as a key (what is what you want if I understood you correctly).
You can also trivially extend this to produce a new dict, which you could use then directly.

```
def getByFirstListElement(k):
        ret = [] #There could be multiple hits, this returns a list of all
        for key, value in onehot.enumerate():
             if value[0] == k:
                 ret.append(value[1])
        return ret
```

---

Version that returns a dictionary:

```
def getPairDict(k):
            ret = {}#There could be multiple hits, this returns a list of all
            for key, value in onehot.enumerate():
                 if value[0] == k:
                     ret.update((value,))#Add the values to the dict
            return ret
```

Answer (score 1):

You can imagine your structure as a multidimensional array at the moment.

If you do: `onehot[0][0] --> 1200`, `onehot[0][1] --> 1`

Iterate through the dictionary as follows:

```
for key in onehot:
    print("{} --> {}".format(onehot[key][0], onehot[key][1]))

result:
    1200 --> 1
    1203 --> 2
    1400 --> 4
```

You can play with your data in any way you see fit :)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I've update the question. I don't want to access  the value by using the ID since I don't which ID is the one for 1200